# Impress Pages - HTML widget not saving/publishing

Tags: impresspages

I'm currently trying to embed a mailchimp sign up form using the HTML widget from impress pages, and at first, it seems to work perfectly fine.

I drag the block onto the screen, a popup comes up, then I paste the form code into it, and then voila! A pretty looking, rendered form appears. I then go ahead and press publish... and bam! My HTML widget is gone, and all that's left is an empty block within the layout asking me to click to add text!

I have no idea what's [going on here](http://harmonyplace.netfirms.com/), does anyone have any ideas? I'm using a custom theme, and I'm wondering if the workaround is to hard-code a widget for my client and just use that (although it looks like it'll be a big drain on my time)

Comment: Can't reproduce. Works fine on default theme. Try following stuff:
- use clean installation of ImpressPages
- make sure you are pasting correct valid HTML
- have a look at System -> log section for any errors

Comment: In addition to that, MailChimp adds its own jquery. And that breaks the management. It is more or less obvious. Here is how you can enter safe mode if HTML widget breaks the management:  http://www.impresspages.org/docs/safe-mode

Answer (score 0):

If you get "Forbidden" as a response after pressing save, you should have a look at the answer here [impresspages html widget not saving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27896925/impresspages-html-widget-not-saving/27898056#27898056)